# Unity prefab script "GameObjects" can't be ones on the scene?

Tags: c#, unity

Currently, I have an object on the scene, and one in prefab. I want the prefab's script to reference to the object on the scene through the

```
public GameObject obj;
```

code. However, when I tried to add the object in the editor, I cant seem to be able to select any objects from the scene, only ones in prefabs.

I am quite new at unity, so am I missing something really basic here?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the gameobject with the code attached selected, you can drag the gameobject in the scene using the hierarchy to the inspector.

Confusing I know, here is a picture:

[image]

EDIT: Strike that, this is more accurate:

With unity, you can not reference things in the hierarchy from a prefab. You need to somehow add it at runtime. A cheap way to do this is to store 'the gameobject in the scene' in a static variable. For instance something like:

```
public static GameObject thingonstage;
void Start(){
    thingonstage = this.gameobject;
}
```

Then later, you reference the static global variable to get at it.

Comment: So to assign the variable, I should make a script for the object that I want to assign, then reference the global variable to set it? Thanks EDIT: I did that, but it didn't seem to work...

Comment: Nevermind, it works! Just that I used a object I dragged out of the prefab, instead of the ones that spawns ingame. Thanks!

Comment: Np, glad to hear you got it to work!

Comment: Hint: The member does not need to be static nor a `GameObject`. Any public `MonoBehaviour` member can be set this way.

Answer (score 1):

Prefabs are supposed to be reusable between different scenes. They can not reference a game object in the scene hierarchy, because that object would be unavailable if the prefab is used in a different scene. That's why prefabs can only reference assets, other prefabs or parts of themselves (like their children).

What you can do instead:

- Have your Start method find the object to interact with in the scene. There are several ways you can do that. You can use [GameObject.Find](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) to find it by name (can be slow if you have a lot of objects in the scene), you can assign an unique tag to the object and then use [GameObject.FindWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html) or you can use the [singleton pattern](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116009/in-unity-how-do-i-correctly-implement-the-singleton-pattern) in a script on the referenced object.
- Assign the object to interact with when you instantiate the prefab. If you spawn the prefab from a script, then that script will need to have a reference to the object. If you create a prefab instance in the Unity editor, you will have to assign that reference manually.

Answer (score -1):

Drag & drop the appropriate gameobject from your scene hierarchy to the property you want to set.