# In Unity, how do I correctly implement the singleton pattern?

Tags: unity, c#, design-patterns

I have seen several videos and tutorials for creating singleton objects in Unity, mainly for a `GameManager`, that appear to use different approaches to instantiating and validating a singleton.

Is there a correct, or rather, preferred approach to this?

The two main examples I have encountered are:

**First**

```
public class GameManager
{
    private static GameManager _instance;

    public static GameManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<GameManager>();
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}
```

**Second**

```
public class GameManager
{
    private static GameManager _instance;

    public static GameManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_instance == null)
            {
                instance = new GameObject("Game Manager");
                instance.AddComponent<GameManager>();
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        _instance = this;
    }
}
```

The main difference I can see between the two is:

The first approach will attempt to navigate the game object stack to find an instance of the `GameManager` which even though this only happens (or should only happen) once seems like it could be very unoptimised as scenes grow in size during development.

Also, the first approach marks the object to not be deleted when the application changes scene, which ensures that the object is persisted between scenes. The second approach doesn't appear to adhere to this.

The second approach seems odd as in the case where the instance is null in the getter, it will create a new GameObject and assign a GameManger component to it. However, this cannot run without first having this GameManager component already attached to an object in the scene, so this is causing me some confusion.

Are there any other approaches that would be recommended, or a hybrid of the two above? There are plenty of videos and tutorials regarding singletons but they all differ so much it is hard to drawn any comparisons between the two and thus, a conclusion as to which one is the best/preferred approach.

Comment: What is said GameManager supposed to do? Does it have to be a GameObject?

Comment: It's not really a question of what the `GameManager` should do, rather how to ensure there are only ever one instance of the object and the best way to enforce that.

Comment: There is actually a pseudo official way to use Singleton in Unity. [Here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton) is the explanation, basically create a Singleton class and make your scripts inherit from that class.

Comment: this tutorials very nicely explained, how to implement singleton http://www.unitygeek.com/unity_c_singleton/ , I hope it is usefull

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It depends, but usually I use a third method. The problem with the methods that you used is that in the event that the object is included to begin with, it will not remove them from the tree, and they can still be created by instantiating too many calls, which could make things really confusing.

```
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour {
    private static SomeClass _instance;

    public static SomeClass Instance { get { return _instance; } }


    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance != null && _instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        } else {
            _instance = this;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with both of your implementations is that they do not destroy an object that is created later. It could work, but one could throw a monkey wrench into the works that could result in a very difficult to debug error down the line. Make sure to check in Awake if there is an instance already, and if so, destroying the new instance.

Comment: You might also want `OnDestroy() { if (this == _instance) { _instance = null; } }`, if you want to have a different instance in each scene.

Comment: Instead of Destroy()ing the GameObject you should raise an error.

Comment: Possibly. You might want to log it, but I don't think you should raise an error, unless you are trying to do something very specific. There are many instances I can imagine that raising an error would actually cause more problem then it would fix.

Comment: You may want to note that MonoBehaviour is spelled with the British spelling by Unity ("MonoBehavior" won't compile--I do this all the time); otherwise, this is some decent code.

Comment: I know I'm coming late, but just wanted to point out, that this answer's singleton does not survive an editor reload, because the static `Instance` property gets wiped.An example of one that does not can be found either in one of the answers below, or https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton (which might be outdated though, but seems to work from my experimenting with it)

Comment: In terms of naming, I use GameManager or AppManager for class name, and then I use _sharedManager as the instance name. Just a note so it makes more sense to read the code.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Super late to the party, but you didn't include a `DontDestroyOnLoad()` in your example, is that still needed in your approach?

Comment: ```DontDestroyOnLoad``` is required if you want the singleton object to persist across scenes.

Answer (score 49):

Here's a quick summary:

```
                 Create object if  Removes scene  Global    Keep across
                 not in scene?     duplicates?    access?   Scene loads?

Method 1            No                No            Yes        Yes

Method 2            Yes               No            Yes        No

PearsonArtPhoto     No                Yes           Yes        No
Method 3
```

So if all you care about is global access, all three get you what you need. [Use of the Singleton pattern can be a bit ambiguous about whether we want lazy instantiation, enforced uniqueness, or global access](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/singleton.html) so be sure to think carefully about why you're reaching for the singleton, and choose an implementation that gets those features right, rather than using a standard for all three when you only need one.

(eg. if my game will always have a GameManager, maybe I don't care about lazy instantiation - maybe it's only global access with guaranteed existence & uniqueness I care about - in which case a static class gets me exactly those features very concisely, with no scene loading considerations)

...but definitely don't use Method 1 as written. The Find can be skipped more easily with Method2/3's Awake() approach, and if we're keeping the manager across scenes then we very likely want duplicate-killing, in case we ever load between two scenes with a manager already in them.

Comment: Note: it should be possible to combine all three methods to create a 4th method that has all four features.

Comment: The thrust of this answer isn't "you should look for a Singleton implementation that does it all" but rather "you should identify which features you actually want from this singleton, and choose an implementation that delivers those features - even if that implementation is not a singleton at all"

Comment: That's a good point DMGregory. Wasn't really my intent to suggest "smash it all together" but that "nothing about these features that prevents them from working together in a single class." i.e. "The thrust of this answer is NOT to suggest *pick one.*"

Answer (score 38):

The best implementation of a generic `Singleton` pattern for Unity I know of is (of course) my own.

It can do *everything*, and it does so *neatly* and *efficiently*:

```
Create object        Removes scene        Global access?               Keep across
if not in scene?     duplicates?                                       Scene loads?

     Yes                  Yes                  Yes                     Yes (optional)
```

Other advantages:

- It's **thread-safe**.
- It avoids bugs related to acquiring (creating) singleton instances when the application is quitting by ensuring that singletons cannot be created after `OnApplicationQuit()`. (And it does so with a single global flag, instead of each singleton type having their own)
- It uses Unity 2017's Mono Update (roughly equivalent to C# 6). (But it can easily be adapted for the ancient version)
- It comes with some **free candy!**

---

And because *sharing is caring*, here it is:

```
public abstract class Singleton<T> : Singleton where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region  Fields
    [CanBeNull]
    private static T _instance;

    [NotNull]
    // ReSharper disable once StaticMemberInGenericType
    private static readonly object Lock = new object();

    [SerializeField]
    private bool _persistent = true;
    #endregion

    #region  Properties
    [NotNull]
    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (Quitting)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning($"[{nameof(Singleton)}<{typeof(T)}>] Instance will not be returned because the application is quitting.");
                // ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
                return null;
            }
            lock (Lock)
            {
                if (_instance != null)
                    return _instance;
                var instances = FindObjectsOfType<T>();
                var count = instances.Length;
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    if (count == 1)
                        return _instance = instances[0];
                    Debug.LogWarning($"[{nameof(Singleton)}<{typeof(T)}>] There should never be more than one {nameof(Singleton)} of type {typeof(T)} in the scene, but {count} were found. The first instance found will be used, and all others will be destroyed.");
                    for (var i = 1; i < instances.Length; i++)
                        Destroy(instances[i]);
                    return _instance = instances[0];
                }

                Debug.Log($"[{nameof(Singleton)}<{typeof(T)}>] An instance is needed in the scene and no existing instances were found, so a new instance will be created.");
                return _instance = new GameObject($"({nameof(Singleton)}){typeof(T)}")
                           .AddComponent<T>();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region  Methods
    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_persistent)
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        OnAwake();
    }

    protected virtual void OnAwake() { }
    #endregion
}

public abstract class Singleton : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region  Properties
    public static bool Quitting { get; private set; }
    #endregion

    #region  Methods
    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        Quitting = true;
    }
    #endregion
}
//Free candy!
```

## How to Use It

```
public class YourManager : Singleton<YourManager>
{
}
```

or

```
public class GameManager : Singleton<GameManager>
{
// Your game-specific variables
  protected override void OnAwake()
  {
    // If needed, put your code here e.g. init your vars.
  }
}
```

When you want to get the singleton object from other scripts, you will write:

```
YourManager.Instance.[Your Method or Variable]
GameManager.Instance.[Your Method or Variable]
```

Comment: This is pretty solid. Coming from a programming background and non-Unity background, can you explain why the singleton isn't managed in the constructor rather than in the Awake method? You can probably imagine that to any developer out there, seeing a Singleton enforced outside of a constructor is an eyebrow raiser...

Comment: @netpoetica Simple. Unity does not support constructors. That's why you don't see constructors being used in any class inheriting `MonoBehaviour`, and I believe any class used by Unity directly in general.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how to utilize this.  Is this meant to simply be the parent of the class in question?  After declaring `SampleSingletonClass : Singleton`, `SampleSingletonClass.Instance` comes back with `SampleSingletonClass does not contain a definition for Instance`.

Comment: @BenI. You have to use the generic `Singleton<>` class. That is why the generic is a child of the base `Singleton` class.

Comment: This is a MonoBehaviour, and probably accessed from other MonoBehaviours. Then why would you need thread safety knowing they are all running from a single Unity thread?

Comment: @PaimanRoointan The code from unity-events (update, fixedupdate, etc) runs on the single thread, but you're forgetting that multi-threaded code can call methods in this class, to run on their own threads.

Comment: @XenoRo FindObjectsOfType which is called inside Instance property will basically not work if called from a different thread than the main thread. It raises an ArgumentException: Find can only be called from the main thread exception.

Comment: the Quitting static variable doesn't work with the new Enter Play Mode options of Unity. See here why: https://forum.unity.com/threads/configurable-enter-play-mode.768689/

Comment: In addition to the point Paiman Roointan raises above, even if you were to populate the existing instances in a different way, the attempt to create the instance on demand here is also not valid off the main thread. Trying to access `Instance` off the main thread can throw the exception "Internal_CreateGameObject can only be called from the main thread." So this approach to spawning the instance on demand can only work if you guarantee the first access to the instance will always be from the main thread.

Comment: Hi @XenoRoI got this error in Unity2019.3.9f1 after paste code in my script.cs: `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CanBeNullAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` any Idea ?

Comment: In case this comes up for future readers: [the CanBeNullAttribute is part of ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#CanBeNullAttribute), a Visual Studio extension that helps with code analysis, testing, and generally catching errors before they bite you, among other handy tricks to help you work efficiently. If you don't use ReSharper, you can skip those attributes when implementing your own version of this answer.

Comment: What's the purpose of the empty `protected virtual void OnAwake` method?

Comment: @GayanWeerakutti If I remember correctly, it's to allow/offer an overridable alternative to `Awake`, that will run it's code after the base `Awake`, while keeping the base method encapsulated and inaccessible, as modifying or overriding the base method might break the persistence code.

Comment: @XenoRo Persistence does not work on child objects, right?

Comment: @GayanWeerakutti You mean unity game objects, or C# objects? If C#, the class is abstract so it's required to inherit this rather than use directly. If Unity, the question is nonsensical, as hierarchy structure has nothing to do with this code. --- Either way, if you want this or the object containing this to be child of something, go for it.

Comment: @XenoRo I meant attaching this script as a component to a child game object. Thanks, I got what you're saying.

Comment: @XenoRo You said "Unity does not support constructors." This is not true. And cannot be true because it's part of the C# language. Every time `new ClassName()` is used, a constructor is called. Within Unity, often the default (parameterless) constructor is called.

Comment: @PaulMasri-Stone Go ahead and try instantiating a gameobject with `new Gameobject()` instead of `Instantiate()` then. --- Constructors are part of the C# language; you're right. But ***unity*** does not support them. See? Context matters. =_=

Answer (score 11):

I'd just like to add that it may be useful to call `DontDestroyOnLoad` if you want your singleton to persist across scenes.

```
public class Singleton : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    private static Singleton _instance;

    public static Singleton Instance 
    { 
        get { return _instance; } 
    } 

    private void Awake() 
    { 
        if (_instance != null && _instance != this) 
        { 
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            return;
        }

        _instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option might be to split the class into two parts: a regular static class for the Singleton component, and a MonoBehaviour that acts as a controller for the singleton instance. This way you have full control over the singleton's construction, and it will persist across scenes. This also lets you add controllers to any object that might need the singleton's data, instead of having to dig through the scene to find a particular component.

```
public class Singleton{
    private Singleton(){
        //Class initialization goes here.
    }

    public void someSingletonMethod(){
        //Some method that acts on the Singleton.
    }

    private static Singleton _instance;
    public static Singleton Instance 
    { 
        get { 
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new Singleton();
            return _instance; 
        }
    } 
}

public class SingletonController: MonoBehaviour{
   //Create a local reference so that the editor can read it.
   public Singleton instance;
   void Awake(){
       instance = Singleton.Instance;
   }
   //You can reference the singleton instance directly, but it might be better to just reflect its methods in the controller.
   public void someMethod(){
       instance.someSingletonMethod();
   }
}
```

Comment: This is very nice!

Comment: I am having trouble understanding this method, can you expand a little more on this subject. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my implementation of a singleton abstract class below. Here is how it stacks up against the 4 criteria

```
             Create object   Removes scene   Global    Keep across
           if not in scene?   duplicates?    access?   Scene loads?

             No (but why         Yes           Yes        Yes
             should it?)
```

It has a couple of other advantages compared to some of the other methods here:

- It doesn't use `FindObjectsOfType` which is a performance killer
- It's flexible in that it doesn't need to create a new empty gameobject during the game. You simply add it in the editor (or during the game) to a gameobject of your choosing.
- It's thread safe

  ```
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using UnityEngine;

  public abstract class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : Singleton<T>
  {
      #region  Variables
      protected static bool Quitting { get; private set; }

      private static readonly object Lock = new object();
      private static Dictionary<System.Type, Singleton<T>> _instances;

      public static T Instance
      {
          get
          {
              if (Quitting)
              {
                  return null;
              }
              lock (Lock)
              {
                  if (_instances == null)
                      _instances = new Dictionary<System.Type, Singleton<T>>();

                  if (_instances.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
                      return (T)_instances[typeof(T)];
                  else
                      return null;
              }
          }
      }

      #endregion

      #region  Methods
      private void OnEnable()
      {
          if (!Quitting)
          {
              bool iAmSingleton = false;

              lock (Lock)
              {
                  if (_instances == null)
                      _instances = new Dictionary<System.Type, Singleton<T>>();

                  if (_instances.ContainsKey(this.GetType()))
                      Destroy(this.gameObject);
                  else
                  {
                      iAmSingleton = true;

                      _instances.Add(this.GetType(), this);

                      DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
                  }
              }

              if(iAmSingleton)
                  OnEnableCallback();
          }
      }

      private void OnApplicationQuit()
      {
          Quitting = true;

          OnApplicationQuitCallback();
      }

      protected abstract void OnApplicationQuitCallback();

      protected abstract void OnEnableCallback();
      #endregion
  }
  ```

Comment: Might be a silly question, but why did you make the `OnApplicationQuitCallback` and `OnEnableCallback` as `abstract` instead of just empty `virtual` methods? At least in my case I don't have any quit/enable logic and having an empty override feels dirty. But I might be missing something.

Comment: @JakubArnold I haven't looked at this in a while but at first glance it looks like you're right, would be better as virtual methods

Comment: @JakubArnold Actually I think I remember my thinking from back then: I wanted to make aware those who used this as a component that they could use `OnApplicationQuitCallback` and `OnEnableCallback`: having it as virtual methods kind of makes it less obvious. Maybe slightly weird a thinking but as far as I remember that was my rational.

Comment: I know this is old but I have a couple of questions.... Why use OnEnable rather than Awake? And why use a dictionary rather than just a single instance? It makes me think like there could be multiple instances

Answer (score 2):

I will trow my implementation too for future generations .

```
void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
        else if (instance != this)
            Destroy(gameObject.GetComponent(instance.GetType()));
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
```

For me this line `Destroy(gameObject.GetComponent(instance.GetType()));` is very important because once I had left a singleton script on another gameObject in a scene and the whole game object was being deleted. This will only Destroy the component if it already exists.

Comment: wouldn't 'instance' be pointing to a destroyed object with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a singleton class that makes easy to create singleton objects. Its is a MonoBehaviour script, so you can use the Coroutines. Its based on this [Unity Wiki article](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton), and I will add option to create it from Prefab later.

So you don't need to write the Singleton codes. Just download [this Singleton.cs Base Class](https://github.com/bivisss/unity-reusable-singleton/blob/master/Singleton.cs), add it to your project, and create your singleton extending it:

```
public class MySingleton : Singleton<MySingleton> {
  protected MySingleton () {} // Protect the constructor!

  public string globalVar;

  void Awake () {
      Debug.Log("Awoke Singleton Instance: " + gameObject.GetInstanceID());
  }
}
```

Now your MySingleton class is a singleton, and you can call it by Instance:

```
MySingleton.Instance.globalVar = "A";
Debug.Log ("globalVar: " + MySingleton.Instance.globalVar);
```

Here is a complete tutorial: http://www.bivis.com.br/2016/05/04/unity-reusable-singleton-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Alright, and here's my Singleton, which has the additional advantage of initializing lazily and detecting infinite initialization loops.

If you want it to not destroy on load you should set this up in your inheriting class. It will use `FindObjectOfType` if necessary, as sometimes you may want to access this from another object's `Awake` method.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

namespace Feed {
  public abstract class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : Singleton<T> {
    static T s_instance;
    static bool s_isInitializing = false;

    protected abstract void Initialize();

    public static bool TryGetInstance(out T instance) {
      if (s_isInitializing) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
          "Singleton initialization dependency cycle detected"
        );
      }
      if (s_instance == null) {
        var found = FindObjectOfType<T>();
        if (found == null) {
          instance = null;
          return false;
        }
        InitializeAndAssign(found);
      }
      instance = s_instance;
      return true;
    }

    public static T Instance {
      get {
        if (TryGetInstance(out var instance)) {
          return instance;
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not find instance of {typeof(T).Name} in scene");
      }
    }

    void Awake() {
      if (s_instance == null) {
        InitializeAndAssign((T) this);
      } else if (s_instance != this) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
          $"Tried to create two instances of singleton {typeof(T).Name}"
        );
      }
    }

    protected virtual void OnDestroy() {
      s_instance = null;
    }

    static void InitializeAndAssign(T instance) {
      if (s_instance != null) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Singleton already exists");
      }
      s_isInitializing = true;
      instance.Initialize();
      s_isInitializing = false;
      s_instance = instance;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jpgordon00/UnitySingleton

All you have to do is add 'SceneSingletonListener' to your scene and you can create singletons like so:
using UnityEngine;

public class SingletonComp : Singleton
{
}

// in any class during runtime...
SingletonComp = SingletonComp.Instance;

Comment: Your code is missing a license and is hence unusable.

Comment: There is now a license, but that license is the GNU GPL, which makes it pretty much useless for any game you intend to sell.