# How to reference a script that's on just one object in the same scene via code?

Tags: unity, c#

```
private TileMovement tileMovement;
```

As you can see in the code above I am trying to reference a `TileMovement` script, where I have some getters and setters that I want to access. I have just one instance of this script, and it's sitting on another object in the same scene.

The problem is, I don't know how to get the reference to that script instance, without doing `[Serialized Field]` or making it `public`, which I 100% don't want to do.

So how would I reference it purely with code, and no use of the editor?

Comment: Does this question help you? "[In Unity, how do I correctly implement the singleton pattern?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116009/in-unity-how-do-i-correctly-implement-the-singleton-pattern)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have just one object in this scene that has a TileMovement component, you can find that unique instance like so:

```
void Start() {
    tileMovement = FindObjectOfType<TileMovement>();
}
```

[This is easy to find in the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html), and in gobs of tutorials online, so be sure to do some basic searching before posting here — you'll save yourself some time by answering your own questions without having to explain your situation and wait for someone to answer.

---

When you want to do this with a component you wrote yourself, another popular method is to make it a [Singleton](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/singleton.html) with a static instance getter, something like:

```
public class TileMovement {
    static TileMovement _instance;
    public static TileMovement Instance => _instance;

    void Awake() {
        if (_instance != null) {
            Debug.LogWarning("Two TileMovement components in scene, but there should be only one!");
            Destroy(this);
        } else {
            _instance = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Then code can just say `TileMovement.Instance` when it wants to interact with that unique instance, without incurring any search cost, and without caching its own `tileMovement` variable.

You want to be careful with singletons, because they're mutable global state (bug risk) and lock you into only ever having one (tricky to refactor if you later find a need for multiple), but the same goes for the `FindObjectOfType` solution, so at least it's not adding *new* problems in that regard.

Comment: Cheers. I should have done more research tbh, I think I just wasn't sure how to formulate the question for Google to find the answer. A bit of noobie, not that patient. Need to learn patience if I want to get into coding. :)