# Implement Singleton that loads before Awake

Tags: unity, c#, design-patterns

I would have liked to comment on [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/116010/170622) answer, but I don't have enough reputation so I had to open this new one. The issue with it (and with the rest of the answers) is that it doesn't work well if another instance tries to access the singleton in its own `Awake`. As far as I know, the order in which `Awake` functions execute can't be configured, so nothing prevents some other class to call the singleton getter before it has initialized the instance:

```
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour {
    private static SomeClass _instance;

    public static SomeClass Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance != null && _instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        } else {
            _instance = this;
        }
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass : MonoBehaviour {
    private void Awake() {
        Foo bar = ResourceManager.Instance.bar; // NullReferenceException here
    }
}
```

I have been trying to change the implementation to initialize `_instance` in the getter, but I can't get through the static enforcement. Any ideas on how to ensure that `SomeClass` gets its `_instance` running before any `Awake` on other classes may ask for it?

Comment: "As far as I know, the order in which Awake functions execute can't be configured" If I recall correctly, you can configure the order of Awake with the [Script Execution Order settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html)

Comment: @DMGregory is correct, although there is a bit of complication if you have multiple scenes open at the same time, as the Awake method of all MonoBehaviours in the first scene will always be called before any MonoBehaviours in the next one. 
An alternative that might or might not work for you, depending on what this Singleton is doing, is to instantiate it the first time someone tries to access it through the `instance`property. Or maybe you can use [RuntimeInitializeOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, for simple cases, this can be solved by moving your earlier dependency up in the [Script Execution Order settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html).

Another way is to make `Instance` a getter method that finds the reference in the scene if it hasn't yet been assigned, and initializes it on demand:

```cs
public abstract class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T :Singleton<T>
{

    static T _instance;

    public static T Instance {
        get {
            if (_instance == null) {
                _instance = FindAnyObjectByType<T>();
                // Here you can assert and
                // log an error if the scene
                // is missing an instance.
                _instance.Init();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    // Override this for any code that should
    // run before this object's first use.
    virtual void Init() {}

    // This bit is optional. You can leave it out
    // for lazy initialization on first use,
    // or keep it to always initialize on load.
    void Awake() {
        if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(_instance, this)
        {
            if (_instance != null) {
                Destroy(this.gameObject);
            } else {
                _instance = (T)this;
                Init();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This version searches the active scene, but you can implement more complex logic in the getter for searching multiple scenes or constructing the instance on demand if needed.